# Grammar meaning question: would and will

Tags: grammar, meaning, ielts

what is difference about meaning between these two sentences?:

sentence 1 : To get a high score you **would** have to study a lot

sentence 2 : To get a high score you **will** have to study a lot

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 is a conditional referring to a hypothetical situation. I could truthfully say, “I would have to study a lot to get a high score in an examination in classical Aramaic”. But sentence 2 is unconditional and refers to an actual state of affairs, so I couldn’t say, “I *will* have to study a lot to get a high score in classical Aramaic”, because in fact I have no intention of taking such an examination.